# How to insert php generated gif to database and upload the gif to folder?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching the solution to generate gif using php. I found one but I couldn't insert the gif into my server folder. I tried to upload jpeg images and i use the move_uploaded_files, it works well. But using this code to generate gif, move_uploaded_files does not work for it. Does anybody know how to move the generated gif into my folder without downloading it as an attachment?

```
<?php
require "../IP/config.php";

if(isset($_POST['preview']))
{
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    if(isset($_POST['download'])){

 // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="animated.gif"');
 //$insert="INSERT INTO content(image,name,address,contactno,price,star_rating,room_qty,userid) VALUES ('animated','est','test','123','120','3','3','1')";
 //mysqli_query($con,$insert);




}
include('GIFEncoder.class.php');
function frame($image){
    ob_start();
    imagegif($image);
    global $frames, $framed;
    $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
    $framed[]=50;
    ob_end_clean();
}
$cnt = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

for($key=0;$key<$cnt;$key++)
{
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
         $im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp_name));
        $resized = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['width'],$_POST['height']);
        imagecopyresized($resized, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
        frame($resized);
}
$gif = new GIFEncoder($frames,$framed,0,2,0,0,0,'bin');
echo $gif->GetAnimation();
$filepath="../IP/image".$_POST['width'];
//move_uploaded_file($gif,$filepath);
copy($gif,$filepath);

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name='robots' content='index,follow' />
    <title>Create GIF image using php</title>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <style>
    input{
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    }

    .center{
    width:205px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    clear:both;
   }
    </style>

</head>
<center>
    <div id="forms" class="menu">
        <h1>GIF Generator</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>

                    </script>
                    <script language=Javascript>
                    function isNumberKey(evt)
                    {
                        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                            return false;

                    return true;
                    }
                    </script>
                <div class="center">
                    <label>SPEED:</label><br>
                        <input name="speed" maxlength="10" type="text" placeholder="Speed in MS" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="padding:5px;"><br><br>
                    <label>WIDTH: </label><br>
                        <input name="width" maxlength="4" type="text" placeholder="Width" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="padding:5px;"><br><br>
                    <label>HEIGHT: </label><br>
                        <input name="height" maxlength="4" type="text" placeholder="Height" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="padding:5px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" style="padding:10px; background:#00A2E4; border-radius:5px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;" name="preview" value="Preview">
                        <input type="submit" style="padding:10px; background:#15A915; border-radius:5px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;" name="download" value="Download">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    </center>

</html>
```

Comment: `$filepath="../IP/image".$_POST['width']` means people can upload files anywhere on your system, possibly trashing your application and/or introducing malware and hacks.

Comment: @tadman that supposed to be comment because I am trying out to find the solution